# Number functions and other functions issue

Tags: javascript, function, numbers

Can someone logicaly explain why fallowing function return error

```
50.toFixed(2);
```

and this not

```
(50).toFixed(2);
```

Same happening with other similar number functions

Comment: you could spend another dot for using an integer number `50..toFixed(2));`